# How to open an encrypted dmg file in Windows?

Tags: windows, encryption, dmg

I made encrypted disk image on my MacBook.
Now I want to open it on my PC (Windows 10).

How can I open (mount) an encrypted dmg image file in Windows 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [website](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/) HFSExplorer can open and read encrypted dmg images.

> HFSExplorer is an application that can read Mac-formatted hard disks and disk images.
>   It can read the file systems HFS (Mac OS Standard), HFS+ (Mac OS Extended) and HFSX (Mac OS Extended with case sensitive file names).
>
> HFSExplorer allows you to browse your Mac volumes with a graphical file system browser, extract files (copy to hard disk), view detailed information about the volume and create disk images from the volume.
>   HFSExplorer can also read most .dmg / .sparsebundle disk images created on a Mac, including zlib / bzip2 compressed images and **AES-128 / AES-256 encrypted images**. It supports the partition schemes Master Boot Record, GUID Partition Table and Apple Partition Map natively.

[Download link](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/catacombae/hfsexplorer-0.23.1-setup.exe?use_mirror=).

Comment: I tried HFSExplorer, it ask for password which I tipped and then show empty system folder (dmg image is encrypted with AES 256, and is correctly opened only with Mac OS).

Answer (score 0):

You can open encrypted dmg file with [TransMac](http://downloads.tomsguide.com/TransMac,0301-34641.html).
It's a very nice software instead of dmg extractor (it's not free, that's why I don't like it). I opened my dmg encrypted file with it on deleted some things and that's all..

Comment: Got an error message from TransMac: "Encrypted volumes not supported"