# Where could be the ringtones, wallpapers located on iOS IPSW package?

Tags: dmg, ringtones, ipsw, ios

I've used and already extracted the IPSW of iOS 11, there are 4 DMG files there, where could that be on that DMG files there, and where exactly insider one of there could I find that such files?

Comment: Interesting how it's referred to as WWDC 2017 and WWDC 2016 as a wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

They're in the biggest of the three DMGs (the one containing the root file system, it's 2.3GB in my IPSW), under `/Library/Wallpaper/iPhone`:

[image]

Ringtones can be found in the same DMG, under `/Library/Ringtones`.

Comment: I wanna ask, can this be done on Windows. Because since this is past iOS 10.3, there's this one named 5.APFS, is that where's you're saying it's located? It looks like it's already in APFS. I wanna ask if there's still no way to open APFS on Windows yet? If there's none, it looks like I need to snag an iOS IPSW lower than iOS 10.3

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/229904/121968) might help to open a DMG in Windows.